# when create row in table take value from another table in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have two Tables. While creating a new invoice, take field "emp_code"  from "HrEmployee" where user=user and insert "emp_code" in the field "sup_emp_code" in "Invoice"

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User,db_column='user', related_name="user_name", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    id_invoice = models.AutoField(db_column='Id_Invoice', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    code_invoice = models.CharField(db_column='Code_Invoice', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    code_auto_invoice = models.IntegerField(db_column='Code_Auto_Invoice', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    invoicedate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='InvoiceDate', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    id_store = models.IntegerField(db_column='Id_Store', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sup_emp_code = models.IntegerField(db_column='Sup_Emp_Code', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

class HrEmployee(models.Model):
    emp_code = models.AutoField(db_column='Emp_Code', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    hr_employeegroupid = models.IntegerField(db_column='Hr_EmployeeGroupId', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    full_name = models.CharField(db_column='Full_Name', max_length=350, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    firstname = models.CharField(db_column='FirstName', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lastname = models.CharField(db_column='LastName', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    birthdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Birthdate', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pic = models.BinaryField(db_column='Pic', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    active = models.IntegerField(db_column='Active', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

signal

```
def createdesktopuser(sender,**kwargs):

       created = kwargs['created']
       instance = kwargs['instance']
       name= instance.username
       online_id = instance.id
       gro= instance.is_staff
       if created:

        add_user = HrEmployee(
            user_id=online_id,full_name=name,)
        add_user.save()
post_save.connect(createdesktopuser,sender=User)
```

Comment: The way you have defined your models is very confusing. You have user_id in your employee table but it is not a foreign key. In your invoice, you already have user as a foreign key, so why you need emp_code. You can get employee code by using user relationship only.

Comment: It is an already existing database connected to the desktop application and it is required to make an application with the same data and the same method of work so I am forced to use it